# Two Visual Studio Online Accounts

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I work for two commercial entities and want to use separate Visual Studio Online accounts (Visual Studio, Azure, Online Git, etc.) for each. I'm happy to purchase a Visual Studio license for each commercial entity but will I be able to successfully switch between accounts within a single installed version of Visual Studio on one development machine?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, in the same way that you can switch between two different installed TFS servers, or two different Git repositories, etc.